# Laravel: Get ManyToMany relationship that is shared by multiple users simultaneously

Tags: laravel

I have such relationships:

```
Chat->belongsToMany(User)
User->belongsToMany(Chat)
```

I need to query the relationships in such a manner that I get the Chat that belongs to 2 users simultaneously.

Is there an elegant way to do it with Laravel without looping through `$user->chats` then inside looping through `$chat->users` and find if  one of the users is the second user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with the intersection to get all the common chats:

```
$commonChats = $userA->chats->intersect($userB->chats);
```

Or, through a query:

```
$commonChats = $userA->chats()->whereHas('users', function($q) use($userB) {
    $q->where('id', $userB->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed!